# PHP displaying image with header broken

Tags: php, image, header

I'm trying to display an image to be used in an `<img />` tag but this code displays a broken image. I know the file exists (see if file_exists line), I'm getting a file size, and the content type is being set correctly. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

```
$image_path = "../../../uploads/theimage.jpg";

$image_info = pathinfo($image_path);

$image_ext = $image_info["extension"];

switch( $image_ext ) {
    case "gif": 
        $content_type="image/gif"; 
        break;
    case "png": 
        $content_type="image/png"; 
        break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": 
        $content_type="image/jpeg"; 
        break;
    default:
        die("invalid image type");
        break;
}

if (file_exists($image_path)) {
    header('Content-Type:'.$content_type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($image_path));

    echo file_get_contents($image_path);
} else {
    echo 'no file?';
}
```

Comment: instead of `file_get_contents` use [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Yup, I've tried that, no luck.

Comment: If you view the source of the "page"/broken image, what do you see?

Comment: It won't let me since it thinks it's an image.

Comment: I don't know if it will show anything meaningful, but it will let you if you comment out the content-type line

Comment: Ya if I comment out the content-type header I get a whole bunch of alien that looks like a jpg file.

Comment: I ran your script, and it works just fine as is. This must be a problem with the page that contains the `<img>` tag

Comment: Or maybe an issue with your image?